# Random body Background Color each second

Tags: javascript, html

i made this function called makeRandColor which creates a random color with RGB and template string literals, but it's been bugging me to know how to make it work each second, i tried settime interval but it doesnt seem to work, am i missing something?

[image]

what i want it to make is like this, document.body.style.backgroundColor = makeRandColor; ,
but each second with settimeinterval

Comment: well just in case u would want to stop the interval later on, save the interval in a variable `let v=setInterval(function(){document.body.style.backgroundColor=makeRandColor()}, 1000)` and the time is in milliseconds. To clear this interval, `clearInterval(v)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to use it like this:

```js
const makeRandColor = () => {
        const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)
        const g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)
        const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)
  
        return `rgb(${r},${g},${b})`
     }
     
setInterval(() => {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = makeRandColor();
    },1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample solution:

```
    const changeBackground = (element) => {
      const random0To255 = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
        return () => {
            element.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${
              random0To255()}, ${
              random0To255()}, ${
              random0To255()})`;
             }
       };

setInterval(changeBackground(document.querySelector('body')), 1000);
```

Comment: Please make sure to explain why your code works. This helps others learn from your answer.

Comment: I have done some refactoring. Now it is better because code is more readable. Elyer I use IEFI function but it was unnecessary.